# Well-defined symbolic integral leading to ConditionalExpression

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, complex, assumptions

I would like to determine a closed-form expression for the following symbolic integral

$$ \int_{-1/2}^{1/2} \!\!\!\! \mathrm{d} x \int_{-1/2}^{1/2} \!\!\!\! \mathrm{d} y \, \frac{1 + b x + c y}{1 + e x + f y + i \eta} \, ,$$

where the coefficients appearing in this expression are such that

$$
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle b,c,e,f \in \mathbb{R} \, ,
\\
\displaystyle \eta \in \mathbb{R}\, , \, \eta \neq 0 \, .
\end{cases}
$$

As a consequence, this integral is always well-defined since its denominator is never equal to 0. To compute this integral in Mathematica, I used the instruction :

```
int = Integrate[(1 + b x + c y)/(1 + e x + f y + I \[Eta]), {x, -1/2,1/2}, {y, -1/2, 1/2}, Assumptions -> {b \[Element] Reals, c \[Element] Reals, e \[Element] Reals, f \[Element] Reals, \[Eta] \[Element] Reals, \[Eta] != 0}]
```

After a quite long calculation (260s) on my computer with Mathematica 10.0.2, I obtained a result of the form

```
int = ConditionalExpression[......,(f<-2 && (2+f<e<0 || (e>0 && 2+e+f<0))) || (-2<f<0 && ((2+e+f>0 && e<0) || 0<e<2+f)) || (0<f<2 && (-2+f<e<0 || (e>0 && e+f<2))) || (f>2 && ((e+f>2 && e<0) || 0<e<-2+f))]]
```

Why do I obtain a result with a ConditionalExpression, while my integral should always be correctly defined ? How should I proceed to *convince* `Integrate` that this integral is always well-defined ?

I noticed that the result inside the `ConditionalExpression` involves terms of the form `ArcTan[(2 \[Eta])/(-2+e+f)]`, which partially explain the constraints obtained.

Another issue is that the result inside the ConditionalExpression also involves complex logarithmic terms of the form `Log[2-e-f+2 I \[Eta]]` . I know that the complex logarithm has a branch-cut so that the result may not be robust when being evaluated.

Would it also be possible to obtain a result that would not involve expression with branch-cuts, so that the results would always be straightforwardly well defined ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can gain insight by evaluating and then simplifying the indefinite integrals.

```
Integrate[(1 + b x + c y)/(1 + e x + f y + I η), y, x, Assumptions -> {x ∈ Reals, 
  y ∈ Reals, b ∈ Reals, c ∈ Reals, e ∈ Reals,f ∈ Reals, η ∈ Reals, η != 0}];
ans = Collect[%, {ArcTan[η/(1 + e x + f y)], Log[1 + e^2 x^2 + 2 f y + f^2 y^2 + 
  2 e (x + f x y) + η^2]}, Simplify]
```

The result is free of conditions but contains an `ArcTan` function, which is multi-valued, changing sign at `1 + e x + f y == 0`.

```
(* ((I/2)*(f*(b*(e^2*x^2 - (1 + f*y + I*η)^2) + 2*e*(1 + e*x + I*η)) - 
            c*e*(1 + e*x + I*η)^2)*ArcTan[η/(1 + e*x + f*y)])/(e^2*f^2) + 
   (y*(f*(-4*e + b*(2 + 2*e*x + f*y + (2*I)*η)) + 
            c*e*(2 + 2*e*x - f*y + (2*I)*η) + 2*e*f*(2 + c*y)*
                Log[1 + e*x + f*y + I*η]))/(4*e^2*f) + 
    ((f*(b*(e^2*x^2 - (1 + f*y + I*η)^2) + 2*e*(1 + e*x + I*η)) - 
            c*e*(1 + e*x + I*η)^2)*Log[1 + e^2*x^2 + 2*f*y + f^2*y^2 + 
                2*e*(x + f*x*y) + η^2])/(4*e^2*f^2) *)
```

A sample plot of `Im[ans]` is given by

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[Im[ans] /. {b -> 3, c -> 3, e -> -3, f -> 3, η -> .1}], 
  {x, -1/2, 1/2}, {y, -1/2, 1/2}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50, 
  AxesLabel -> {x, y, "Im[ans]"}, ImageSize -> 500, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However, obviously the integral itself is not discontinuous, the discontinuity in `ans` arising from the branch cut in `ArcTan`.  But, we are free to choose a different branch that eliminates this spurious discontinuity.  Doing so can be accomplished by defining

```
myarctan[z_] := Piecewise[{{ArcTan[z], z > 0}, {Pi + ArcTan[z], z < 0}}, Pi/2];
```

and making the substitution

```
ans = ans /. ArcTan -> myarctan
```

The redefined `ans` is continuous.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Alternative to myarctan**

The substitution

```
ans = ans /. ArcTan[z_] :> Pi/2 - ArcTan[1/z]
```

has the same effect as `ans = ans /. ArcTan -> myarctan` but does not require definition of a new function.  This alternative is based on equations 4.236 and 4.239 of the [digital revised version](http://dlmf.nist.gov/4.23) of *Handbook of Mathematical Functions*.

**Addendum**

In answer to the additional question posed in a Comment below, the corresponding definite integral is given by

```
(ans /. {x -> 1/2, y -> 1/2}) - (ans /. {x -> 1/2, y -> -1/2}) - 
  (ans /. {x -> -1/2, y -> 1/2}) + (ans /. {x -> -1/2, y -> -1/2})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems indeed, that considering the indefinite integral allowed to obtain *simple* expressions. Once you have determined the indefinite integral, how would you proceed to determine the value of the integral for $x \in \{ -1/2, 1/2\}$ and $y \in \{ -1/2, 1/2 \}$ ?

Comment: @jibe I have provided an updated answer to the question in your Comment as an addendum to my earlier Answer. Basically, you must take account of the discontinuity at `1 + e x + f y == 0`.

Comment: @jibe I eliminated the discontinuity in my most current update, eliminating the need to worry about conditions.

Comment: In your updated answer, you indeed manage to get rid of the discontinuity present in `Im[ans]`. However, you only checked visually by looking at the case `{b -> 3, c -> 3, e -> -3, f -> 3, η -> .1}`. How can we be sure that for any other values of `e` and `f` there will be no discontinuities ? How general is your modifcation of `ArcTan` ? (I was worried by the presence of `Log[1 + e*x + f*y + I*η]` for other discontinuities, but because `η != 0`, this function will never cross the branch-cut, so that the only issue is indeed the `ArcTan`.)

Comment: @jibe As you noted in your last Comment, the `Log` terms are continuous for real `x` and `y`.  That leaves the `ArcTan` term, which has a discontinuity only at `1 + e x + f y == 0`, and `myarctan` fixes that.  So, I am confident that there are no other discontinuities.  But, just to be sure, I looked at several other representative sets of `e` and `f` and found none.

Comment: Your use of the identity linking `ArcTan[z]` and `ArcTan[1/z]` is all I needed to be completly convinced that with your substitution the branch-cut discontinuity is never met. Thank you for your help and your various updates !

Answer (score 5):

One way to approach this is to look for the source of the problem. In this case, the outer integral (on y) is irrelevant to the problem, because even the simpler integral

```
int = Integrate[(1 + b x)/(1 + e x + I η), {x, -1/2, 1/2}, 
  Assumptions -> {b ∈ Reals, c ∈ Reals, e ∈ Reals, η ∈ Reals, η != 0}]
```

gives a conditional expression. But now the answer is smaller and easier to see. The answer contains the term

```
Log[2 - e + 2 I η]
```

and the condition is that `-2 < e < 2`. So what is happening is that you are encountering different branches of the Log function.

You can evaluate this for different branches. For instance, instead of the assumption `e ∈ Reals`, use `e<-2`, `e>2` or `e==0`. These all return (nonconditional) answers. The last one is even simple:

```
1/(1 + I η)
```

Hopefully these answers can feed back into the original problem with the double integral.

Comment: Indeed, looking at the simpler case of only one integral is a good way to look at this problem. Once you have obtained this result with a `ConditionalExpression`, how would you evaluate it for $|e < 2|$, $|e| > 0$ or even $e = 0$ ?

Comment: @jibe -- see update

Comment: Thank you, I believe this approach should allow me to obtain the expressions needed. The only remaining task for me is to correctly *partition* the $(e,f)$ space so as to be able to handle all cases. In case of trouble with the general case, I will come back to you.