# Want to eliminate conditions from result of Integrate

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis

This is my first time using Mathematica for the purpose of solving complex integrals. I have to compute few complex integrals which have many coefficients. For example,
    $$\int_0^\infty \frac{k^2\, (k^2 + p^2)^{1/2}}{(k^2 + u^2)^2\, (2\, k^2 + 2\,p^2 + m\,(k^2 + p^2)^{1/2}\,)}\, dk $$

When I am trying to calculate it with `Integrate`, the result is always with a `ConditionalExpression` with some real and imaginary conditions.
I know that there is a solution to this integral because my professor calculated it some time ago and I have to repeat it.

I also have few principal value integrals to calculate. But the results of them are even more complex.

Could you give me some advice on what should I do to get rid of the conditions?

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted some examples on this website in *Mathematica* code.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46453/when-to-use-generateconditions-true/46492#46492.  Some related: [(13275)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13275), [(37588)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37588), [(78385)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78385)

Answer (score 2):

This

```
Assuming[u>0 && m>-2,
  Integrate[k^2 Sqrt[k^2+p^2]/((k^2+u^2)^2 Sqrt[2 k^2+2 p^2+m (k^2+p^2)]),
    {k,0,Infinity}]]
```

instantly returns Pi/(4 Sqrt[2+m] u).

If you look at the arguments inside the Conditional and what I put inside my Assuming then you might see how this is done.

You can use slightly different assumptions and still eliminate the conditional.

Answer (score 2):

```
int = Integrate[
  k^2 Sqrt[k^2 + p^2]/((k^2 + u^2)^2 Sqrt[2 k^2 + 2 p^2 + m (k^2 + p^2)]), {k,
    0, Infinity}]

(*  ConditionalExpression[
   Pi/(4*Sqrt[2 + m]*u), 
   Re[u] > 0 && Re[m] > -2 && 
     Im[m] == 0]  *)
```

You can extract the desired result from the answer using [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html)

```
int[[1]]

(*  Pi/(4*Sqrt[2 + m]*u)  *)
```

As shown by @Bill, you can use assumptions consistent with the conditions given in the [`ConditionalExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html)

```
Assuming[{m > -2, u > 0},
 Integrate[
  k^2 Sqrt[k^2 + p^2]/((k^2 + u^2)^2 Sqrt[2 k^2 + 2 p^2 + m (k^2 + p^2)]), {k,
    0, Infinity}]]

(*  Pi/(4*Sqrt[2 + m]*u)  *)
```

Or you can tell Mathematica to not generate conditions (**EDIT:** this has some risk as pointed out in the comment by @mattiav27)

```
Integrate[k^2 Sqrt[
    k^2 + p^2]/((k^2 + u^2)^2 Sqrt[2 k^2 + 2 p^2 + m (k^2 + p^2)]), {k, 0, 
  Infinity}, GenerateConditions -> False]

(*  (Pi*Sqrt[1/u^2])/(4*Sqrt[2 + m])  *)
```

Which may then need simplification with assumptions to arrive at the same end result

```
Simplify[%, u > 0]

(*  Pi/(4*Sqrt[2 + m]*u)  *)
```

Comment: You should also say that using `GenerateConditions->False` might be dangerous: see this answer: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/108578/8822 and also the documentation of `Integrate`. The problem is that it will *"Generate a result without conditions that is **valid only for some values** of parameters"*

Comment: The canonical way to remove the `ConditionalExpression` is by using `Normal` (see docs on `Normal`).

Comment: @QuantumDot - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for help.
However in your code, there was a small mistake in denominator. It should look like this:

`Integrate[k^2 Sqrt[k^2 + p^2]/((k^2 + u^2)^2 (2 k^2 + 2 p^2 + m Sqrt[k^2 + p^2])), {k, 0, Infinity}, GenerateConditions -> False]`

This makes calculations much longer. The result is really long with some signs that I don't fully understand. This is a part of result:

```
                                2    2
           2  2         I Sqrt[p  - u ]
    (2 I) m  p  Log[1 - ---------------] + 
                               u

                             2    2
           4         I Sqrt[p  - u ]
    (8 I) p  Log[1 - ---------------] + 
                            u
```

Do you know what that "I" means? I tried to find it in some library as a special function or constant but without success.

I also have a problem with functions containing logarithm:

```
int = Integrate[k Log[(Sqrt[k^2 + p^2]+k)/(Sqrt[k^2 +  p^2]-k)]/((k^2 + u^2)^2 (2 k^2 + 2 p^2 + m Sqrt[k^2 + p^2])), {k,0, Infinity}]
```

A computer that I am working on at my University simply don't want to give me the result probably because of some time limit. Is there a way to force Mathematica to compute the result in such a situation?

Thank you for help one more time. :)